# how to iterate and append jsonb in postgres db function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql, jsonb

I have a DB function, say `"myWrapperFunction"()`, which returns a JSON array of objects as below:

```
select * from "myWrapperFunction"()

>> [{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]
```

I have a table "table1" with column 'column1'.

I need to pass the values from `table1.column1` into `myFunction()` as argument and build one json array from the results.

I have created the below db function and it works fine with only one problem: **it appends an empty json object at the start**:

```
[{},{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"e":"f"},{"k":"l"}]
```

How to get rid of that leading empty json object?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myWrapperFunction()
    RETURNS SETOF json 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    STABLE STRICT 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    _elements INTEGER[];
    _element INTEGER;
    _results json;
    _result json;
    _all_result jsonb;
    val json ='{}'::json;

BEGIN
  SELECT  ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT column1) into _elements from table1;
  FOREACH _element IN ARRAY _elements 
  LOOP
        SELECT * FROM  myFunction(_element) into _results; 
    IF _results IS NOT null THEN
        val=val::jsonb||_results::jsonb;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN QUERY select val;
  RETURN  ;
END; $BODY$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value for `val` is `val json ='{}'::jsonb;` which is later concatenated inside the loop:

```
val=val::jsonb||_results::jsonb;
```

For sample:

```
SELECT '{}'::JSONB || '[{"a":"b"}]'::JSONB;
-- [{}, {"a": "b"}]
--  ^^
```

It could be replaced with `val json ='[]'::jsonb;`:

```
SELECT '[]'::JSONB || '[{"a":"b"}]'::JSONB
-- [{"a": "b"}]
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/g2FQmXF9)**

Answer (score 1):

The added empty object noise can be avoided like instructed by Lukasz.

While being at it, start over. Almost everything else is incorrect or inefficient, too:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_wrapper_function()
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(my_function(column1)::jsonb), '[]'::jsonb)
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table1) sub;
$func$;
```

That's assuming `my_function()` is actually `STABLE`.

Or just use the bare SQL statement, there is little utility in the remaining `my_wrapper_function()` now.
You may not even need `COALESCE`, nor the added cast:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(my_function(column1))
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table1) sub;
```

A query with an aggregate function and no `GROUP BY` always returns exactly one row.